# reattach database jobs to another identical schema

Tags: oracle, jobs

I have a working DB holding schema1.
I needed to clone the schema1 to schema2. I did this with `expdp` and `impdp`. Everything worked fine, least when doing `impdp` for metadata I got the following error:

> ORA-39083: Object type JOB failed to create with error:
>   ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYS.I_JOB_JOB) violated
>   Failing sql is:
>    BEGIN SYS.DBMS_IJOB.SUBMIT( JOB=> 3, LUSER=> 'SCHEMA2', PUSER=> 'SCHEMA2', CUSER=> 'SCHEMA2', NEXT_DATE=> TO_DATE('2017-10-30 11:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI:SS'), INTERVAL=> 'trunc(sysdate,''HH24'')+1/24', BROKEN=>  FALSE, WHAT=> 'a_database_job;', NLSENV=> 'NLS_LANGUAGE=''AMERICAN'' NLS_TERRITORY=''AMERICA'' NLS_CURRENCY=''$'' NLS_ISO_CURRENCY=''AMERICA'' NLS_N

Now the way I read this is because of the jobs that were trying to get in the `SYS.DBMS_IJOB` and keep he same number perhaps for the second schema.

So my question is *How do I migrate the / a set of jobs from schema1 to schema2 - can this be done by just changing the owner?*

hope there is enough data here.

Comment: You may have some incomplete jobs that became orphans; you might need to look at the `dba_scheduler_jobs` view to see if something needs cleaning up.  Also check permissions on the user ID you are using for the `expdp` and `impdp` jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `DBMS_IJOB.CHANGE_ENV`.

```
PROCEDURE CHANGE_ENV
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 JOB                            BINARY_INTEGER          IN
 LUSER                          VARCHAR2                IN
 PUSER                          VARCHAR2                IN
 CUSER                          VARCHAR2                IN
 NLSENV                         VARCHAR2                IN
```

Example:

```
declare
  my_job number;
begin
  dbms_job.submit(job => my_job, 
    what => 'begin null; end;',
    next_date => sysdate+1,
    interval => 'sysdate+1');
end;
/

SQL> select job, log_user, priv_user, schema_user, what from dba_jobs;

       JOB LOG_USER   PRIV_USER  SCHEMA_USER WHAT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- --------------------
         1 SYS        SYS        SYS         begin null; end;

begin
  for j in (select * from dba_jobs where job = 1)
  loop
    dbms_ijob.change_env(j.job, 'BP', 'BP', 'BP', j.nls_env);
  end loop;
  commit;
end;
/

select job, log_user, priv_user, schema_user, what from dba_jobs;

       JOB LOG_USER   PRIV_USER  SCHEMA_USER WHAT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- --------------------
         1 BP         BP         BP          begin null; end;
```